# error in attempt to use tasks.py in django celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I try to do something very basic with celery and django. Specifically in my app in tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
app = Celery( broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

and in views.py of this app:

```
from .tasks import *

def index(request):
    add.delay(4, 4)
    return HttpResponse("you are in index")
```

when I start running celery and go to index the celery process raises the error.

I run:

```
celery -A tasks worker
```

and the error is:

```
[2017-04-14 00:53:12,404: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task 
of type 'rango.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?'
```

what do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the current registered celery tasks in in the `celery.registry.TaskRegistry` class?

Comment: Show us your `celeryconfig` file or settings, would like to know what you have put for `CELERY_IMPORTS`

Comment: just a copy-paste from celery documentation about django.
I uploaded it [here, on GithHub: https://github.com/chapkovski/tango](https://github.com/chapkovski/tango)   

in settings.py:

     `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
     CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 
     'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
     CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 
     "django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"
      CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'`

thank you!!

Comment: try adding `CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks",)` there too

Comment: yes, it works, but I needed to add the path to add. like:

`CELERY_IMPORTS = ("rango.tasks",) `